# Spring Upload to server and saving file path to database

Tags: spring, file, download

I'm using spring framework 3.2 for my project and I have a form with many form elements and upload function. I want to save the form to the database and at the same time upload the file to my local drive, then save the path of the file to the database.

The file path will be used to retrieve the file later on.

I'm able to save the form as an object by itself to the database but I'm not sure how to go about integrating the upload save to server and adding the path to the database. I would appreciate any pointers on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload a file please</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Please upload a file</h1>
        <form method="post" action="/form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html> 



@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        // store the bytes somewhere
       return "redirect:uploadSuccess";
   } else {
       return "redirect:uploadFailure";
   }
}

}
```

[reference 1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-forms)

[step by step](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/upload-files-with-spring-mvc-eclipse-based-tutorial?showall=1&limitstart=)